# scope.$watch still return $rootscope:infdig

Tags: angularjs

Good day!

I have an issue with scope.$watch.

Previously my app returned $rootscope:infdig error. After doing some research, it is because I didn't use scope.$watch. So, I added the scope.$watch.

Now, it still return the same error. Did I miss anything?

In directive.js

```
scope.checkDetail = function() {
     scope.$watch(function () {
          return scope.button;
     }, function () {
          SendInterview.getDetail(candidateID).then(function (result) {
               scope.interviewDetail = result;
          });
          if(interviewDetail.status){
                scope.button = true;
          }
     });
}
```

This is my .html

```
<a type="button" ng-disabled="checkDetail()">BUTTON</a>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[$rootscope:infdig](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig) happens when you have an infinite $digest loop.
In your case you're watching $scope.button and updating it in your trigger, thus triggering it over and over again.

Comment: okay. so how can I fix this problem? because I tried to use scope.$watch and it is still not working

Comment: Your checkDetail function should return either true or false.
I don't think you need $watch.